# Parse string with JS to pull out words between several special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like:

```
lorem ipsum !bang #hash #hash2 ^caret word @at sym
```

I am trying to pull out the words beginning with the various characters - sometimes they can have a space in them, and there can be multiple of each type. So I want to convert this string to a set of values such as:

```
text: "lorem ipsum"
!: "bang"
#: ["hash", "hash2"]
^: "caret word"
@: "at sym"
```

It always starts with just the plain string. So far, I've tried a few things, but can't quite get it. For example, I tried splitting the string into an array of words, which kind of works except for spaces:

```
var list = str.split(' ');

var hashes=[];
$.each(list,function(i,val){
    if(list[i].indexOf('#') == 0){
      hashes.push(tagslistarr[i]);  
    }
});

//Result: [hash, hash2]
```

So this works, but obviously breaks as some can have spaces. It also means duplicating that code for each of the `^ # ! @`.

I also tried:

```
str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("^")+1,str.lastIndexOf("@"));
```

Which does return `caret word` with the space correctly, but fails to take account of all the characters. I tried replacing "@" with an array, but no luck.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Many thanks

**Edit:** Just a note that the various parts can be in any order, as could the amount of them, and they don't all have to be present. So could be `ab !a #b #c #d ^f b a @a` or `cd ^x y !a`

Comment: Will the string in question always have the same order viz "plain string !exclamation words #hash words ^caret words @at words" ?
Are there any other symbols?

Comment: No sorry, order could be different, as could the amount of them, and they don't all have to be present. So could be `ab !a #b #c #d ^f b a @a` or `cd ^x y !a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at below JS code. Hope it will help you to achieve your goal.

```js
var inputString = "lorem ipsum !bang #hash #hash2 ^caret word @at sym";
var specialChars = "!#^@";
var firstSpecialCharIndex = inputString.search(/[!#^@]/);
var plainText = inputString.substring(0, firstSpecialCharIndex);
var result = {};
result["text"] = plainText;

for (i = firstSpecialCharIndex + 1; i < inputString.length;) {
  var modifiedString = inputString.substring(i);

  var currentChar = inputString.charAt(i - 1);
  if (result[currentChar] == null)
    result[currentChar] = [];
  var text = "";
  var specialCharIndex = modifiedString.search(/[!#^@]/);
  if (specialCharIndex != -1) {
    text = modifiedString.substring(0, specialCharIndex);
    text = text.trim();
    result[currentChar].push(text);
    i += specialCharIndex + 1;
  } else {
    text = modifiedString.substring(0);
    text = text.trim();
    result[currentChar].push(text);
    i = inputString.length;
  }


}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Wow, that's fantastic, thanks! Just tested it with several variations and it works perfectly. Will mark as answer :)

Comment: welcome @samiles. Enjoyed a lot writing above generic code. Thanks...`:)`!

Answer (score 0):

Will the various types of data, i.e. no special character, then !, then #, then ^, then @ always be in the same order?

lorem ipsum !bang #hash #hash2 ^caret word @at sym

If so, you could write an extractor function for each type of data, which used the bounding characters to detect the word section, for example, if you want to get out bang, you detect position of !, then detect position of #.  You then know boundary positions of data, extract that data and clean up to get words.  For # section, you go from position of # to position of ^, extract section and clean up to get words, etc.

Comment: No sorry, order could be different, as could the amount of them, and they don't all have to be present. So could be `ab !a #b #c #d ^f b a @a` or `cd ^x y !a`. Should have mentioned this, otherwise this approach might work. But I think if I attempt to just pull chars between ! and #, it could contain a ^ or something else.